# Deploying database to azure error SQL72014

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I try to deploy a database to Microsoft Azure it generates this error .

> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 40548, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Granting CONNECT permission to the guest user in database 'ACS Database' is not permitted.

Although the guest user has connect permission.

Any help?

Comment: Do you use SQL Azure or SQL Server on VM?

Answer (score 3):

The situation you described is fairly vague- so I cannot be sure why you're seeing this error or what circumstances could be causing you to see it.

However, you should [avoid using the guest user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb402861.aspx) for user databases as a best practice; you should instead [Grant permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx) explicitly to avoid the situation where every user that logs into your database has access (and any other permission `guest` has) to this database.